# Unable to install pymssql - no matching distribution found for pymssql

Tags: python, sql, pymssql

```
C:\>pip install --proxy "http://dcullen:password@1.2.3.4:80" pymssql
Collecting pymssql
Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement pymssql (from versions
: )
No matching distribution found for pymssql
```

I am trying to use the above command to install the pymssql module. I can install other modules through my proxy, so I don't think the proxy is the issue.

**Python version:** `Python 2.7.11 (v2.7.11:6d1b6a68f775, Dec  5 2015, 20:40:30) [MSC v.1500 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32`

I also tried downloading and installing the 64 bit wheel file, but got the following error:

```
C:\>pip install pymssql-2.1.2-cp27-cp27m-win_amd64.whl
pymssql-2.1.2-cp27-cp27m-win_amd64.whl is not a supported wheel on this platform
```

Comment: Works fine for me, it could be your proxy. Try downloading the file `pymssql-2.1.2-cp27-cp27m-win32.whl` directly from https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pymssql/2.1.2 and install it using `pip`.

Comment: Just tried that, updated answer

Comment: Re-read my comment. You are downloading the `amd64` version while your Python is `win32`.

Comment: Tried them both, I have the 64 bit version of python...

Comment: download this file and run http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#pymssql

Comment: Tried all 3, same error message - is not a supported wheel on this platform.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Upgrading my pip to the latest version seemed to do the job.

The use of `--index-url=http://pypi.python.org/simple/ --trusted-host pypi.python.org` was also required as stated in this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25981703/pip-install-fails-with-connection-error-ssl-certificate-verify-failed-certi).

Comment: In addition to this I was getting a DLL error when importing. I ended up having to install the 32 bit version of python and the 32bit version of the pymssql module and install from wheel